# New page will not display when following hyperlink in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am almost completely done developing a small project which accesses the Twitch API to display the online/offline status of streams as part of the FreeCodeCamp curriculum.

You may view the project here: https://codepen.io/MikeLuDev/pen/qXVarP

After fetching API results I use the following code to create a new link to each each result:

```
let newLink = $("<a></a>");
newLink.prop({id:linkID,
             class:linkID + " " + isOnline,
             href:"https://www.twitch.tv/" + stream, 
             target:"_blank", 
             rel:"noopener"
             });

$("#content").append(newLink);
```

I have tested this on the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome. On Chrome the program works as intended. However, on Firefox the link opens in a new tab but the page never displays and only shows a white screen. This happens on my office computer, home desktop, and mobile phone. Nothing odd appears in the console when trying to open the links.

When removing the following lines

```
target:"_blank",
rel:"noopener"
```

and opening the links in a new tab by clicking the middle-mouse button the page loads correctly.

Is there a fix for this?

edit: I should also add that when the previous two lines are still in the code and the middle mouse button is used the page opens correctly.

edit2: here is an [image of my screen when opening a new link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyiYZ.png)

edit3: I thought of the possibility that it is my adblocker. After disabling that the problem still persists.

Comment: Why you need rel:"noopener"

Comment: Using target: "blank" by itself presents a security vulnerability which noopener prevents.

Comment: The point is may be that link need some referer of what coming to it. If you dont have it it gone blank. Try to remove rel: 'noopener" to see if it works

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: It's seem that your example work for my firefox. Can you take a screen shot? or console

Comment: Your network has some problem then

Comment: I updated my original post with a screenshot. How could it be the network if it only occurs in Firefox and not other browsers?

Comment: Just asking, because it work on my firefox developer edition. Will try normal firefox then

Comment: Interesting, Its only happen if you click the link in side codepen iframe. If you open the frame in new tab then try the link it will work

Comment: confirming what @TrinhHoangNhu said,, I got it working correctly on my firefox v55.0.1 (64-bit) ,, what addons do you use in ff,, I got my clean

Comment: I disabled all addons and cleared my cache, the problem still persists. I only have Reddit Enhancement Suite and uBlock Origin.

Comment: @MichaelLu are you logged in in twitch account maybe? try to open this in FF private mode..

Comment: @KresimirPendic in private mode the app works as intended. That's odd. Edit: I logged out of twitch and it now works in regular browsing.

Comment: no it's not,, remember that,, I use chrome constantly and I also use incognito mode for testing.. rigor network, dns and content caching browsers have this days.. :) good luck, and also, cool app!

Comment: Could you try on your local instead of codepen please. I think they add something else.

Comment: @KresimirPendic Thanks so much!